# "last seen time" for a term in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping that has a host and a timestamp (among other fields), and would like to get a "last seen time" for some number of recently seen hosts.  Is there a better way to do this than to first do a term facet on the host field, then a range query (limit=1) on each of the term values sorted in descending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A term stats facet would bring back the min/max for the timestamp for each host wouldn't it?

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "host_time_stats" : {
            "terms_stats" : {
                "key_field" : "host",
                "value_field" : "timestamp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```